# subtract hundredths write the correct condition

Tags: php

I receive value from a DB
`$row['jackpot']` it is equal to 5000.00

how to write the correct condition?

```
if ($row['jackpot'] < '2000.00') {

      $asd = "2000.00" - $row['jackpot'];
      echo "To participate you are missing".$asd;
}
```

Comment: remove the single quote and double quote from digit (2000.00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of `jackpot` column? If it is string then you need to make it float, only then `<` operator will be work in `if statement`.

```
$row_jackpot = (float)$row['jackpot'];
if ($row_jackpot  < 2000.00) {

      $asd = 2000.00 - $row_jackpot;
      echo "To participate you are missing".$asd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format()` if you want to keep two decimals

```
$jackpot = (float)$row['jackpot'];
if ($jackpot < 2000) {
  $asd = number_format(2000 - $jackpot, 2);
  echo "To participate you are missing".$asd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `$row['jackpot'] = 1000.00;`

Then try this

```
if ($row['jackpot'] < 2000.00) {
$asd = number_format(2000.00 - $row['jackpot'], 2);
echo "To participate you are missing " . $asd;
}
```